# Error while running storybook with create react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app, storybook

I have installed storybook into my existing repo. When I try to run storybook. I get the following error.

> Your project's `baseUrl` can only be set to `src` or `node_modules`. Create React App does not support other values at this time.

My current folder structure has app at root level. Hence my baseURL at tsconfig.json is ./app. I have tried things listed here [Github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3916#issuecomment-409698193) but this dint work for me. This is my current folder structure.

[image]